# Tic Tac Toe winning condition checks (confused)

Tags: javascript

Following a simple tutorial but just cant understand how the program determines if you've won the game. It looks so simple but I don't understand how a,b & c been true results in the game been won. When I console.log a,b & c as I click on a cell I can see a corresponds to the first nine of winningConditions values, b corresponds to the next nine and c to the last six.

So clicking on cells 0,1 & 2 is not going to make a,b and c equal.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

```
    let gameState = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    let currentPlayer = "X";

    const winningConditions = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];

    function handleResultValidation() {
        let roundWon = false;
        for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
            const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
            let a = gameState[winCondition[0]];
            let b = gameState[winCondition[1]];
            let c = gameState[winCondition[2]];
    
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
            console.log(c);
            if (a === '' || b === '' || c === '') {
                continue;
            }

            if (a === b && b === c) {
                roundWon = true;
                break
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you feel that one of the post below answers your question,  - pls mark that as the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop you check, for each win condition, if it's fullfiled.

Let's check how it works for `i` equal `6`.
So you check if this win condition is true:

```
X##
#X#
##X
```

You then have

```
("=" is a math "=", not programic "=" here)
a = gameState[winCondition[0]] = gameState[0]
b = gameState[winCondition[0]] = gameState[4]
c = gameState[winCondition[0]] = gameState[8]
```

`gameState` represents your game state in a way that it's an array of 9 elements, and the field

```
123
456
789
```

is represented as `gameState = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

So you check the 0th, 4th and 8th field in your game for `i=6`.

If `a === b` and `b === c`, then you have also `a === c`.

So you know that all 3 fields are the same, which fullfils the win condition for `i=6`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the first iteration of the for loop, when `i` is 0, the expression

```
const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
```

will cause the variable `winCondition` to have the value `[0, 1, 2]`, since that is the value at index 0 of `winningConditions`.

Next, the lines

```
let a = gameState[winCondition[0]];
let b = gameState[winCondition[1]];
let c = gameState[winCondition[2]];
```

will set `a` to `gameState[0]`, `b` to `gameState[1]`, and `c` to `gameState[2]`. Suppose `a` holds the value `X`. If `a === b && b === c`, this means the top row in the tic tac toe board is all Xs, meaning the game is over.

Why is `a === b && b === c` sufficient? This is sufficient due the transitive property of equality in math. If, in math, A equals B and B equals C, then A must also equal C. In the case of this tic tac toe implementation, `a === b && b === c` simply checks to see if a, b, and c are all X or all O.

Since the `winCondition` list exhaustively lists all possible ways that a 3x3 tic tac toe game can be won, looping over each possible win condition state will cause a game over state to be detected.